# how to convert a page loaded from protractor to pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, selenium, protractor

I'm loading page like below using protractor

```
await browser.get(url);
```

I can get the page source like this `const html = await browser.getPageSource();`

I just want to convert the page to pdf.

what is the best way do that ?

Answer (score 0):

there are some npm you could install and use to download html pages and convert directly to pdf
example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf